# Sublime -- Setting Default Syntax for *.hbs.html

Tags: sublimetext3

I've started working with MeteorJS, which requires Handlebars templates to end with *.html.

You can't use *.hbs, or Meteor will throw an error.

I'd like to simply use *.hbs.html, so Meteor won't raise an exception, and I'll get the syntax highlighting for Handlebars simultaneously. How can I customize Sublime to recognize *.hbs.html as Handlebars syntax?

UPDATE:

Here's my code for ApplySyntax (not working yet):

```
"syntaxes": [
      {
            "name": "Handlebars",
             "match": "all",
             "rules": [
                 {"file_name": ".hbs.html$"}
             ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in ApplySyntax:

```
"syntaxes": [
  {
    "name": "Handlebars/Handlebars",
    "extensions": ["hbs.html"]
  }
]
```

The key is in the `name` - you need to specify the name of the package AND the path to the `.tmLanguage` file (extension excluded) within that package. I think it's in the root of the Handlebars package in this case, so this should work.

If you need other extensions just add them to that array, or if you need more complex matching you can use regular expressions as outlined in the other answer (or a combination of both).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I needed "Handlebars/Handlebars" to make it happen, although I used the extension from Leonid's code.

Answer (score 2):

By default Sublime Text only uses the last extension part to detect syntax, in your case, it's `html`.

There's a plugin called [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) that can detect syntax by any part of the filename, like `hbs.html`, apart from other things - see the default settings file for examples.

The ApplySyntax configuration should look like

```
"syntaxes": [
        {
             "name": "Handlebars",
             "rules": [
                 {"file_name": ".*\\.hbs\\.html$"}
             ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've installed the package and tried to modify the default - user settings. I'm not getting it to work. Any suggestions? I've added the snippet above.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've also tried: `"name": "Handlebars", "rules": [ {"file_name": ".*\\.html$"}, {"first_line": "^<template name="}`

Comment: @ilrein Sure! Added a snippet

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working without any extra packages. I'm using Sublime Text 3 Build 3126.

1. Open the file whose syntax you want to change
2. Go to *View* → *Syntax* → *Open all with current extension as* → select the appropriate syntax
3. *Preferences* → *Settings - Syntax Specific*
4. Change the extension as appropriate, for example:

   ```
   {
       "extensions":
       [
           "hbs.html"
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Save the syntax settings file